# git fetch blacklist remote

Tags: git, git-fetch

Is there a way to make `git fetch --all`, or alternatively some other flag to `git fetch`, to not fetch from one remote?

I know there is the `git fetch --multiple foo bar baz` but I am looking for something more along the lines of `git fetch --exclude remote_rarely_fetched_from_needs_vpn`.

Otherwise I have to wait for the command to time out from failing to establish a network connection to that remote.

Alternatively, it would work for my case if I can fetch from all remotes with hostname matching `github.com`, but I am interested in seeing all options, if any.

Comment: Do you have a lot of remotes so that it is difficult to list all of the "whitelisted" ones?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have nine total, including the one that I'd like to exclude by default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46857645/404623) got me on the right track. I managed to find this piece of text in the documentation for [`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emupdateem):

> **update**
>
> Fetch updates for a named set of remotes in the repository as defined by remotes.<group>. If a named group is not specified on the command line, the configuration parameter remotes.default will be used; if remotes.default is not defined, all remotes which do not have the configuration parameter remote.<name>.skipDefaultUpdate set to true will be updated.

Digging through the [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-remoteltnamegtskipDefaultUpdate) documentation, I found the option that does exactly what I need:

> **`remote.<name>.skipDefaultUpdate`**
>
> If true, this remote will be skipped by default when updating using [git-fetch[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) or the `update` subcommand of [git-remote[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote).

To set this option on my repo, I simply do this:

```
git config remote.remote_rarely_fetched_from_needs_vpn.skipDefaultUpdate true
```

Comment: Welp, I learned something new today.  Didn't know that was there.

Answer (score 2):

```
git config remotes.usual "origin upstream qa maint vendor and so forth"
git remote update usual
```

if it's easy to list the usual suspects once up front.  To scan your remote urls you can

```
git config --get-regexp remote\\..*\\.url
```

and a little light sed'ing will get you the remote names that have whatever pattern you want.